# SQLite - Trying to read a file with SQL which contains text with special characters causes strange symbols

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to create a SQL script that can be used to generate a database with a set of data, but once I try to read the script in SQLite, special characters(specifically n with tilde) becomes unreadable by humans. Here is an example of a script with the issue:

```
create table if not exists person(
      id integer primary key not null, --auto increment key
      name text NOT NULL
      );

begin transaction;

insert into person(name) values ('señor');

end transaction;
```

Running the Query "SELECT * FROM person;" returns the following result:

```
1|se├▒or
```

My class requires that I am able to show special symbols within the sqlite command line app. If I copy and paste the insert command into the sqlite console, then the value will be displayed properly.

Comment: Are you using the `sqlite3` command-line shell in Windows?

Comment: It seems you aren't using the UTF-8 encoding while retrieving the data from SQLite...

Comment: I have tried in both Windows and Linux by using the same SQL script, but get the same output. I have tried switching the command prompt to UTF-8 by running "chcp 65001", but it seems to make no difference.